# PHP HTML alert box when the registration is successful

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a registration form in html and a php code that connects to the database. Now if the registration is successful and is added to the database, how to i alert the user that it is successful with a popup box?

the html code is just a simple form codes so heres the php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $fname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $mname = $_POST['middlename'];
    $birthday = $_POST['year'] . '/' . $_POST['month'] . '/' . $_POST['day'];
    $sex = $_POST['sex'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $occupation = $_POST['occupation'];
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
    $cfname = $_POST['contactfirstname'];
    $clname = $_POST['contactlastname'];
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysql_select_db('HMIS');

    $query = "INSERT INTO `patientrecords` VALUES('','$lname','$fname','$mname','$birthday','$sex','$address','$telephone','$occupation','$clname','$cfname')";

    if(mysql_query($query)){
        echo "Registered";
    }else{
        echo "Error!". mysql_error();
    }
}

?>
```

I can do the javascript alert box only when a certain button is clicked. But in the php code you dont need a button.. so.. how do you do it?

Comment: You cannot create a pop up box using html and php, use javascript and trigger the lightbox when registration successful

Comment: please stop using `mysql_*` and use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: @itachi why? is there a difference?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @user1551672 **Yes** mysql_* **will be deprecated in near future version**

Comment: I'm surprised why nobody has asked why you're showing a popup instead of just displaying the information on the page after submit/redirect.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw o... brian ..... your idea is far more better

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
if(success)
{
   echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">".
        "alert('success');".
        "</script>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I click on the ok button from the alert, it just redirects to a blank page. I tried adding a header('location:') so it will redirect to the homepage.. but it didnt show the alert box. It instantly redirected to the page where I want it to be.

Comment: I made assumption that you were using the same page where you have your form to do the form processing. If your form `action=""` is a different page, you need to redirect from that page. You can add redirection to that script after the alert: `location.href = "redirection page.php`

Comment: @user1551672 it does not redirects to a blank page. the page is **empty!**

Answer (score 1):

try this it will help and redirect to the another page:

```
if($result){
    echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Succesfully Registered')
    window.location.href='../index.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly trigger a popup winder from PHP as it is a server side language.

You can however echo back html containing javascript to display a popup, but that's a pretty hacky solution.

You should instead look at taking advantage of ajax for something like this.

Also, as @itachi said, don't use msql_* use PDO instead, and make sure you are binding your parameters as you could have some serious security implications by not doing so.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_query($query)){
    $redirectUrl = 'YOUR URL';

    echo '<script type="application/javascript">alert("Registered"); window.location.href = "'.$redirectUrl.'";</script>';
}else{
    echo "Error!". mysql_error();
    //Remove Below comment if you want to also popup an alert on error
    /**echo '<script type="application/javascript">alert("Error! '.mysql_error().'");</script>';*/
}
```

Comment: Like what i said before, when i click ok, it redirects to a blank page. and when i add header location code it doesnt show the alert box.

Comment: Is the page your are having the form on and the page with this php code are different?

Comment: Yes. They are in separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will popup a window , with your success message , Edit in your  form page thanks.

```
<form method=post action="whatever.php" 
onsubmit="window.open('','my_form_target', 'width=300,height=200', true); 
this.target='my_form_target';">
```