# Display alert box upon form submission

Tags: php, html, forms, alert

So I have these two pages: `pageOne.php` and `pageTwo.php`.The form is in `pageOne.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="pageTwo.php"> .... </form>
```

and doing all the data collection-validation-insertion and sending out mails in `pageTwo.php` (the reason i'm doing everything in two separate pages is to avoid the data re-submission upon page refresh...this was the easiest way for me to handle the issue). So far everything is working perfectly.

Now, I want to display a success/failure message using alert box after the form submission and tried few things w/o any luck. E.g. when I tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328791/php-html-alert-box-when-the-registration-is-successful) solution on `pageTwo.php`, no pop up box shows up and I think that's because I have this `header` on top of that page

```
<?php header("Location: http://TestPages.com/pageOne.php");  ?>

<?php
if( $_POST ) {
     //collect the data
     //insert the data into DB
     //send out the mails IFF the data insertion works

     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('It worked!')</script>";
}else
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Did NOT work')</script>";
?>
```

And when tried this  [second solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16250596/successful-fail-message-pop-up-box-after-submit) in `pageOne.php`, I get the alert box popping up every time i refresh the page and get the failure message even though the data had been inserted into database and mails were sent out. `pageOne.php`:

```
<html>
<body>
   <?php
   if( $GLOBALS["posted"])  //if($posted) 
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('It worked!')</script>";
   else
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Did NOT work')</script>";
   ?>
   <form method="post" action="pageTwo.php"> .... </form>
</body>
```

and in `pageTwo.php`:

```
<?php header("Location: http://TestPages.com/pageOne.php");  ?>

<?php
$posted = false;
if( $_POST ) {
     $posted = true;
     //collect the data
     //insert the data into DB
     //send out the mails IFF the data insertion works
}    ?>
```

Why isn't this simple thing working :( ? is there any easy way to fix it? Thank you!!

**UPDATE**

So I have made some changes according to *drrcknlsn*'s sugession and this is what I have so far....`pageOne.php`:

```
 <?php
   session_start();

   if (isset($_SESSION['posted']) && $_SESSION['posted']) {
      unset($_SESSION['posted']);
      // the form was posted - do something here
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('It worked!')</script>";
   } else
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Did NOT work')</script>";
 ?>
<html> <body>
   <form method="post" action="pageTwo.php"> .... </form>
</body> </html>
```

and `pageTwo.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     $_SESSION['posted'] = true;

     //collect the data
     //insert the data into DB
     //send out the mails IFF the data insertion works

     header('Location: http://TestPages.com/pageOne.php');
     exit;
} ?>
```

With these changes now the page's redirection and success message is working, but i get the failure msg every time i open/refresh the page (i know that's because the session key is not set yet)...**how can i avoid that?** Thanks again!!

Comment: So you mean alert('Did NOT work') is showing up everytime ? What does your $GLOBALS have?

Comment: @hrnrgv: Yeap...to first question. stupid question, how do i check what $GLOBALS has?!

Comment: What I meant was if you can do print_r($GLOBALS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a couple points:

1. **Variables (even globals) are not shared across requests** like you're trying to do in your bottom example.  In order for `$posted` to be accessible in both pages, you must persist it in some way.  Usually this involves setting a session variable (e.g. `$_SESSION['posted'] = true;`), but it could also be persisted in a cookie, in a database, on the filesystem, in a cache, etc.
2. **Use something like `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')` instead of `if ($_POST)`.**  While the latter is probably safe in most cases, it's better to get in the habit of using the former because there exists an edge case where `$_POST` can be empty with a valid `POST` request, and it may be a hard bug to track down.

One potential pattern to solve your problem using the above advice:

*pageOne.php:*

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['posted']) && $_SESSION['posted']) {
    unset($_SESSION['posted']);

    // the form was posted - do something here
}
?>
...
<form>...</form>
```

*pageTwo.php:*

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $_SESSION['posted'] = true;

    // do form processing stuff here

    header('Location: pageOne.php');
    exit;
}

// show an error page here (users shouldn't ever see it, unless they're snooping around)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it. but now when i'm doing the suggested changes, first i'm getting warnings on first page (`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent...`)  and the header is not working on second page. It is also giving me errors and not displaying any messages :/

Comment: @Walahh the call to `session_start()` must come before anything else in the script that would write something to the buffer.  That means any markup outside of `<?php ?>` tags, any calls to `header()`, any `echo` or `print` calls, etc.

Comment: up vote for explaining it again! wow, it's working..well, kind of. so now the redirecting is working as well as the success msg. BUT the failure msg is displayed each time the pageOne loads (open or refresh the page)...how can i avoid that?

Comment: just for clarity sake everyone, i "thought" i had the calls before everything as i commented out everything before the `session_start()` . apparently that's not the correct way...i should have deleted them  first time :P

Comment: @Walahh There is no failure message in the code that I posted, so I have no idea what you're referring to or why it's broken.

Comment: I just updated my original question, can you plz take a look?

Comment: @Walahh You've added an `else` block on `pageOne.php` that alerts failure when the session variable isn't set.  The only time the session variable is set is when the form has been posted.  So, you're telling it that any time the form hasn't been posted, treat it as a failure.  Obviously that's wrong.  Just remove the `else` block; it wasn't in my answer.

Comment: sorry 'coz i think i wasn't clear enough in my original post what i am actually looking for. As i mentioned that in `pageTwo` i save the data in the DB and send out mails to the clients-admins. Now i want to display a msg based on the success/failure of that data handling. I already know how to display one alert (in my case the success note) msg, but i need to be able to have options...pick from either success or failure msg based on how the form data was handled. and that's why i added that extra `else` block hoping you could help me with that.

Comment: @Walahh:  I've showed you how to persist data across multiple requests using the session.  Whether or not a post succeeded or failed is just more data.  So, based on that, what do you think should be done?  :-)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it's a scope problem.
use:

```
global $posted = true;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Variables are not shared across requests.  Even global variables.  Each page is served to a different HTTP request.  In order to keep state across multiple requests, you have to persist data somewhere (session, database, filesystem, etc.).