# Show alert from php action page after fetching the records from the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have been trying to show alert message from php action page after the form records are fetched from database. I have 2 php pages. In one.php I am making a ajax call to action page two.php. Till now I am able to make successful ajax call from one.php to two.php and I am able to receive all the parameters passed from one.php to two.php. But I would like to show an alert message in one.php after the records are fetched into the database in the file two.php.

**two.php**

```
$query = "SELECT status FROM dash_apparel_reprint WHERE piece_number='" . $piece_info[0] . "' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != false) {
       $status = $row[0];
    }

    if($status == "New" || $status == "Out of Stock"){
        echo('<script type="text/javascript">window.alert("fetching records done"); window.location.href="one.php"</script>');
        exit();
    }
```

I am using POST method for both one.php and two.php. referring to this [Display alert box upon form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176986/display-alert-box-upon-form-submission)
Any kind of advice or suggestion will definitely help me learn this concept

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: I am not able to display the alert message on one.php. I am still trying to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Hit F12 and look at chrome console for errors. (Also, don't use alert as it's a blocking operation.)

Comment: No errors or warnings as of now

Comment: Do not output scripts from PHP. Just use AJAX to request data from the server and you can do the alert in Javascript

Comment: All your `echo` does is create a response to the ajax request.  Unless you're actually _doing_ something with that response, nothing's going to happen.  But like csandreas1 said, there's really no point doing it the way you are.  Just respond with some sort of success flag, check for that in the response handler, and then alert.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an alert you need to set it in the `success` part of your ajax call. 
See below:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'two.php',
             data: {var1: var1value} //Pass your variables here
             type: 'post',
             success: function(output) {  //This is where you receive the result from two.php
                  //Do whatever you want with the data stored in output
                  alert('It worked!'); //Alert whatever you need here           
             },
             error: function() {
                  alert('That did not work...'); //Handle errors here
             }
        });
```

In the `success` or `error` functions you can update other DOM elements in your page as well, which may be more elegant than just an alert.